# Intersection of a family of compact sets is compact

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Here is the question I'm tackling:

> Suppose $({K_\alpha})_{\alpha \in J}$ is a family of compact subsets of $\mathbb{R}$

Show that $\bigcap_{\alpha J} K_\alpha$ is compact

I'm aware how do prove this for the union using induction but am not sure where to start on this one. If I should also use induction some tips on where to start would be really useful.

Thanks

Comment: Not completely sure how you use induction if the index set is not countable. Indeed you need only to show that it is closed and bounded.

Comment: For union it's false (unless the union is of finitely many sets).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are working in a Hausdorff space (such as a metric space) the
result is true and straightforward to show from the definition.

In a Hausdorff space, compact sets are closed and hence $K=\cap_\alpha K_\alpha$ is closed, and $K^c$ is open.

Let $U_\beta$ be an open cover of $K$, then $U_\beta, K^c$ is an open cover of the entire space.

Select one element $K_{\alpha_1}$ of the collection, then there is
a finite subcover $U_{\beta_1}, \cdots,U_{\beta_n} , K^c$ of $K_{\alpha_1}$. Hence $U_{\beta_1}, \cdots,U_{\beta_n}$ is a finite
cover of $K$.

Answer (score 0):

Compact sets in $\mathbb{R}$ are closed and bounded. The intersection of closed sets in $\mathbb{R}$ is closed. Your intersection of compact sets is contained in any of the compact sets, which are bounded, so it is bounded. Hence the intersection is closed and bounded in $\mathbb{R}$, so it is compact.